# Song playlist recommendation system

Tags: python, dataset, machine-learning-model, recommender-system, model-evaluations

I want to build a recommender system to suggest similar songs to continue a playlist (similar to what Spotify does by recommending similar songs at the end of a playlist).

I want to build two models: one based on collaborative filtering and another one, a content-based model, to compare their results and choose the best one.

Now, I have two questions:

1. Where can I find a dataset with useful data for this type of work?
2. How can I measure the results to choose the best model? How can I understand that a specific song is better than another one to continue my playlist?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Imho it's a bit optimistic, it's not sure at all that this kind of dataset exists, and if it does it might not be free. Data science often starts by finding a way to *collect* some data, it's rarely all ready and available. But if you want you can ask on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/, who knows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Erwan , I'll try.
What about the second question: what metrics can I use to evaluate the "precision" of the suggestions of a recommender system? How can I say if a suggested song, in this case, is the best song to suggest? If another model suggest me another song that I like more, how can I evaluate the results from the two models in order to say which model predicts better songs for me?

Comment: I don't know recommender evaluation very well. For your question it depends what is the goal of the task: is it supposed to recommend a song based on general users tastes, or based on personal choices? The latter is probably harder, because it means that you need some user-specific data for each user (including to train the model).